# Socket comunication Between External Server, Own Server and React Client

Tags: reactjs, express, websocket

I have a server running on express. On this server I connect with an external socket server "wss://..."
I can get the data from this external websocket, but the question is how i send that data to my front end on realtime?
What is the best option?

Comment: is your react client static or ssr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is to establish a connection server - external ws and then I created another connection between my server and the front end.
This works fine.